# Sum values from one of each three columns

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a sheet in which I want to sum the values of Cells M,P,S,V,Y,AB,... of each row; this means, one of each three columns. The value must be returned in cell J of each row. There are about 65 rows, so I need a formula that can be dragged down or basically, that doesn't require formulation on each row.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I managed to do it by using modular arithmetics. The formula is the following

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN(M2:DA2,3)=1,M2:DA2)))
```